# PowerShell Script for Updating ALL users' DisplayName in Active Directory

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Currently our AD DisplayName is "LastName, FirstName". Any pointers on how to write a script to change all users to "FirstName LastName"?

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [MCVE] of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. [SO] is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [Ask] a Good Question (and [How do I ask and answer homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822), if relevant).

Answer (score 1):

I think I've sorted it out:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory  
$users = $null  
$users = Get-ADUser -SearchBase "OU=Users,OU=Redacted,DC=Redacted,DC=Redacted,DC=Redacted" -Filter * -Properties GivenName, Surname
ForEach($user in $users)  
{
    $name = $user.GivenName + " " + $user.Surname
    Set-ADUser -Identity $user.Name -DisplayName $name
}
```